# CSS Grid cell max width

Tags: css, css-grid

I have grid with some divs with paragraphs. I would like to put as many as possible divs in one row, but I want to wrap under divs' width is 600px.

I have problem becouse I want the content of the paragraph to fit in the window when resolution is under 600px (max cell width is equal to resolution)

Can it be done without @media?

```css
.grid{
  display: grid; 
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(600px, 1fr))
}

.element{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class="element">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae </p>
 </div>
<div class="element">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae </p>
 </div>
<div class="element">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae </p>
 </div>
<div class="element">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with @media? It was created to solve tasks like yours. Use it and don't reinvent a wheel.

Comment: media reminds me of measuring pixels with a ruler in many cases. 
Additionally, I use React inline styles and have much work with media. 
I'm just learning and want to make sure that media is correct solution in this case

Comment: In this case media is the most right solution. Anything else will require more code and will look like a workaround.